# Are there physics theorems that can prove maths theorems? Eg Pythagoras' Theorem

Tags: mathematics, geometry, moment-of-inertia, moment

There's this recent post on maths overflow [Which theorems have Pythagoras' Theorem as a special case?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/421829/) that has an [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/421896) by [dxiv](https://mathoverflow.net/users/83134/dxiv) that appears to use a physics theorem to a prove a maths theorem, namely using the [parallel axis (axes?) theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_axis_theorem) to prove Pythagoras' Theorem aka the Pythagorean Theorem.

**Question**: Possibly [n00b question](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/career-advice/ask-yourself-dumb-questions-and-answer-them/), but what are others like this, **if I am interpreting this right**? Can I use, what, [perpendicular axis theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpendicular_axis_theorem) to prove Pythagoras' Theorem? Or some other Physics thing to prove (some version of the) Cauchy–Bunyakovsky–Schwarz inequality? **Or maybe am I misinterpreting this** as a case of physics theorem proving a maths theorem in that, what, we're actually viewing a triangle as like a physics object (or isomorphic to or embedded in some physics object) instead of a maths object? Idk.

I mean, I find this incredible. Of course there are things in maths like using complex analysis to evaluate real integrals or [using probability to solve PDEs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman%E2%80%93Kac_formula) but there isn't really like a 'precedence' issue here.

The closest I know of cases like the above is using a complex analysis theorem to prove a topology theorem (eg [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ORLr.png)) despite that topology kinda 'precedes' complex analysis or something. But no way is this precedence on the same level as like how [maths precedes physics](https://xkcd.com/435/). Viewing maths as like the 'language of science' or whatever. I find this like, I don't know, psychology (taught or studied in English) proving a theorem in the English language or something.

Comment: That thread was not about “proving” things using other disciplines. Really it was about *learning* something about math by considering other disciplines, which frankly happens all the time. Physics is the source of a *lot* of math.

Comment: Theorems are math, not physics. Some are motivated by physics problems, but the foundations of physics are experiments and observations, not axioms and proofs. Consider Boltzmann's "H-theorem". It's not really a theorem, but the phenomena verify it.

Comment: @march So there's like this for chemistry like some chemistry theorem (or theorem used in some mathematical modelling in chemistry or however J. Murray would like to put it...) that can prove Pythagoras' Theorem? Or other disciplines? I'd imagine physics should be the only other relevant discipline here...

Comment: @JohnDoty Ah thanks. So parallel axis theorem is really a literal theorem and thus belongs to maths, even if it's used in physics, but Boltzmann's 'H-theorem' is as much of a 'theorem', as oh idk, 'mathematical induction' is 'induction' (like mathematical induction is really deductive reasoning instead of inductive reasoning)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever a theorem appears in a physics context, it is a mathematical statement made in the context of a mathematical model. Any proof of such a theorem is therefore a purely mathematical statement which cannot be proved by physical data.

As an example, take the parallel axis theorem in 2D.  Let $\rho$ be the (planar) mass density, $M\equiv\int \mathrm d^2 r \  \rho(\mathbf r)$ the total mass of the object, and $\mathbf R\equiv \frac{1}{M}\int \mathrm d^2r \ \mathbf r \rho(\mathbf r)$ the object's center of mass.  Furthermore, we define the moment of inertia about a point $\mathbf r_0$ to be $I(\mathbf r_0) = \int \mathrm d^2 r \ \rho(\mathbf r)|\mathbf r-\mathbf r_0|^2$.  Assuming that these quantities are all well-defined, the parallel axis theorem is simply the statement that $I(\mathbf r_0) = I(\mathbf R) + M|\mathbf R-\mathbf r_0|^2$.

Proof:
$$I(\mathbf r_0) = \int \mathrm d^2r \ \rho(\mathbf r)|\mathbf r-\mathbf r_0|^2 = \int \mathrm d^2r \ \rho(\mathbf r)|(\mathbf r-\mathbf R)+(\mathbf R-\mathbf r_0)|^2$$
$$\underbrace{\int \mathrm d^2r \ \rho(\mathbf r)|\mathbf r-\mathbf R|^2}_{= I(\mathbf R)}+2(\mathbf R-\mathbf r_0)\cdot\underbrace{\int \mathrm d^2r \ \rho(\mathbf r)(\mathbf r-\mathbf R)}_{=0\text{ by def. of }\mathbf R}+ |\mathbf R-\mathbf r_0|^2\underbrace{\int \mathrm d^2r \ \rho(\mathbf r)}_{= M}$$
$$= I(\mathbf R)+M|\mathbf R-\mathbf r_0|^2$$

The heart and soul of this proof is simply algebraic rearrangement. The parallel axis theorem is basically$^\dagger$ equivalent to $|\mathbf a+\mathbf b|^2 = |\mathbf a|^2 +2\mathbf a\cdot\mathbf b+|\mathbf b|^2$ (i.e. the law of cosines), which follows from the definition of the standard inner product on $\mathbb R^3$. So from a logical viewpoint, we have
$$\text{Def. of }\mathbb R^3\text{ inner product} \implies \matrix{\text{Law of cosines}\\\Updownarrow \\ \text{Parallel axis thm}}\implies \text{Pythagorean thm}$$
where the latter arises as a special case when $\mathbf a \cdot \mathbf b=0$.

In any case, there is no sense in which the parallel axis theorem is "proved by physics." It is a somewhat grandiose name for a trivial bit of algebraic manipulation. It cannot be proved by experimental data, so its proof relies on the mathematical assumptions made when we define it in the first place.

---

$^\dagger$Strictly speaking, the parallel axis theorem also relies on the algebraic properties of integrals.

Comment: P.S. consider posting that as an answer on the maths overflow question!

Comment: (1/2) Sounds good. Thanks J. Murray. I think I've really forgotten the parallel axis theorem, so I can't readily understand the 2nd paragraph and the proof. In undergrad, we were required to take physics and we really did learn that. I remember 1 of the mock exam questions was to prove the parallel axis theorem. But anyway...

Comment: (2/2) ...I don't believe I'm too far off in thinking the reason why it appears that a physics theorem can prove a maths theorem is because we're treating a triangle as a physics object (or isomorphic to or embedded in a physics object), perhaps as the projection of some 3D object to the plane? It sounds like this is kinda what's being done when you say 'take the parallel axis theorem in 2D.'

Comment: @BCLC My point is that a "physics theorem" is a **mathematical** theorem which happens to appear in the context of a (mathematical!) model for a physical system. The fact that it is used to predict the results of physical experiments does not mean it isn't a mathematical theorem.

Comment: J. Murray oh right thanks I forgot to change that when copying from my other comment. But anyway what's happening here is that the parallel axis theorem is, what, on mathematical objects in $\mathbb R^3$ and then we're applying it (or projecting it?) to objects in $\mathbb R^2$ ?

Comment: @BCLC To generalize the theorem to 3D, one can define the moment of inertia of an object about an axis defined by a unit vector $\hat n$ through a point $\mathbf r_0$ to be $I(\mathbf r_0,\hat n) = \int \mathrm d^3r \ \rho(\mathbf r) |\hat n \times (\mathbf r-\mathbf r_0)|^2$.  The theorem then generalizes to the statement that $I(\mathbf r_0,\hat n)= I(\mathbf R,\hat n) + M|\hat n\times(\mathbf R-\mathbf r_0)|^2$.

Comment: Ah ok so the [parallel axis theorem on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_axis_theorem#Mass_moment_of_inertia) is really the 2D already?

Comment: @BCLC No.  But the version in wikipedia takes $\hat n$ to be $\hat z$, and $\mathbf r_0=\mathbf 0$; from there, simply note that $|\hat z \times \mathbf r|^2 = x^2+y^2$.

Comment: Ok I think I see it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It's like [dxiv](https://mathoverflow.net/users/83134/dxiv) said. The special case they used here is equivalent to the median length theorem, which is a theorem in math. Besides, I find the idea of using physics to "prove" something in math a bit weird. Physics is an empirical science in the sense that we make measurements and formulate mathematical models that agree with the measurements. Sure, one can use the existing mathematical models to make predictions about measurements that they are yet to take, but that's as far as you can go with the framework of physics. In other words, formal physics can be used to predict or "prove" something concerning physics, but it cannot prove anything in math. I like to think of math as being the explanation for physics and not the other way round, you know? It's the math that explains and helps you understand why something in physics is true, and not the other way round. The proof of a statement is just that; it explains exactly why a statement is true.

Comment: Thanks Aryan Komarla 'I like to think of math as being the explanation for physics and not the other way round, you know?' --> That's EXACTLY what I was thinking right? I was surprised to see a physics answer in maths overflow. To me, that's really philosophically incredible. Anyway I edited post to hopefully be clearer like 'we're actually viewing a triangle as like a physics object (or isomorphic to or embedded in some physics object) instead of a maths object' which is why we can view physics theorems on a triangle ? Idk

Comment: Anyway, even if you say Apollonius's theorem...then ok fine...it's still the same thing I think. The parallel axis theorem implies Apollonius's theorem. Actually I really forgot the  parallel axis theorem. In undergrad, we were required to take physics and we really did learn that. I remember 1 of the mock exam questions was to prove the  parallel axis theorem. But I don't believe I'm too far off in thinking the reason why a physics theorem can prove a maths theorem is because we're treating a triangle as a physics object, perhaps as the projection of some 3D object to the plane?

Comment: Math elucidates the properties of things that exist only in the human mind. Sometimes those things happen to be good models of real things in the physical world. We thus apply math selectively to physics, choosing those objects that serve as successful models. But then, to say that the math explains the physics is circular. The physics determines which math we choose to model it.

Comment: @JohnDoty Doty makes a good point and resolves two issues. Firstly, I was wrong in saying that the math explains the physics. This is because we choose the math to explain the physics. What's surprising is that math is such a good model of physics. Indeed, it's such a good model that often we say that it's the language of physics. Secondly, since the parallel axis theorem is a result of a mathematical model we chose, it "proving" the Pythagorean theorem is again, a result of math, and not some physical law that places this constraint on the sides of a triangle. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're complicating this question.

Pythagoras' theorem was most likely originally an outcome of physics. Recall, that geometry means measurement of the earth. This is a physical act and not a mathematical act - the difference between the two was at least acknowledged by Aristotle's time as he explicitly differentiated them of logical vs physical neccessity.

Thus the Babylonians deduced, or rather, *induced* Pythagoras' theorem on the basis of several empirical observations. Think of that as a geometric experiment.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136224/discussion-on-answer-by-mozibur-ullah-are-there-physics-theorems-that-can-prove).